# FileStream cannot be closed when an exception is occurred in runtime

Tags: c#

The following is a part of my code:

```
try
{
    using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
    {
        .
        .
        .
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Data\Temp", userId + ".xlsx");

        //Load the existing Excel workbook into IWorkbook
        FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        .
        .
        .
        //***For example, an exception is occurred here in runtime***
        .
        .
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

I don't have access to `Close()` method of `FileStream` in `catch` section.
I have to restart the server to close `FileStream`. How can I fix this?

Comment: `using FileStream inputStream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the using statement for the filestream:

```
using var inputStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
```